# Error when creating a StreamingContext

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I open the spark shell

```
spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.0
```

Then I want to create a streaming context

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._


val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
```

I run into a exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at:
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you open the spark-shell, there is already a streaming context created. It is called sc, meaning you do not need to create a configure object. Simply use the existing sc object.

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc,Seconds(1))
```

instead of var we will use val